# passing multiple parameters in href from xslt

Tags: xslt, href

I am transforming an xml document to html by xslt. I am getting wrong output while passing multiple parameters in . Following is the code :

```
<A href='index.html?id={str[2]}&classname={str[3]}'><xsl:value-of select="str[4]"/></A>
```

this works with single parameter.any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you be more precise as to exactly what is 'wrong'. Also, can you give more details as to how you are passing multiple parameters in. Showing your input XML and your XSLT would really help. Thanks!

Comment: i got the solution href written as below works:    <A href='index.html?className=PartyAccount&amp;id={str[2]}'><xsl:value-of select="str[4]"/></A> where PartyAccount is just a string and str[] is  value accessed from xml document. the trick was to use amp instead of &.

Comment: Ah yes, you need to escape the attribute value. Feel free to 'answer your own question', rather than do a comment with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <A href='index.html?id={str[2]}&classname={str[3]}'><xsl:value-of select="str[4]"/></A>
> ```

This is not a well-formed XML document.

In a well-formed XML document, an `&` character that isn't in a comment or isn't used as a start of an entity-reference name, must be escaped.

**This is correct**:

```
<A href='index.html?id={str[2]}&amp;classname={str[3]}'><xsl:value-of select="str[4]"/></A>
```